# Pass data between two fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I want to pass data between two `Fragment` I am adding this method to the Fragment whose sending data.

```
 public void sendData(){
    //Put the value
        FragmentA fragmentA = new 
        FragmentA ();

        String tag = data.TAGS;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("TAG", tag);
        fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
        //Inflate the fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, fragmentA)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

and in the Fragment which recieve information I am adding this code into the `onCreateView`

```
                String tag = getArguments().getString("TAG");
                Log.d("valeur", "valeur=" + tag);
```

the problem is that I am getting data with LOGGer but the app crached and I have this message in the `getString` method,

```
Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String 
android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: check `tag` is null or not at first when sending

Comment: you are adding values in `fragmentA` and in fragmentManager passing `fragmentAddBusinessInfo` because of which `getArguments()` is null

Comment: tag is not null @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: like @NileshDeokar pointed out, you are passing the wrong fragment to the transaction

Comment: no but it was just an error when i writing the question check i am edditind the question

Comment: String tag = data.TAGS; this line is probably null. debug the app and you'll see where the problem is

Comment: @Nenco using log d i have the value of TAG 

" D/valeur: valeur "

Comment: then just check if getArguments!=null and then add your code inside the brackets

Comment: @Nenco thank you it works i just add

if (getArguments() != null) {
              
                String tag = getArguments().getString("TAG");

              
                Log.d("valeur", "valeur=" + tag);
            }

Comment: np, happy coding! :)

Comment: @Nenco you can add an answer and i will make it as as resolved if you want

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
if(getArguments()!=null){

// log your data here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Made Mistake in setArgument

**Here is Your Modified code**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("TAG", tag);
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
//You need to put setArgument Here
fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, fragmentA)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

And at your receiving fragment  You need to check getArgument whether it is fillup with values or not  in onCreateView() method

```
if(getArgument != null){
String tag = getArguments().getString("TAG");
}
```